# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, database

I get these errors in my logcat when i tried to change my project build target to 4.1 google API, in Project Properties. I've tried to fix project properties and clean project, but with no success. What's the problem?

```
10-07 15:13:34.839: E/Trace(731): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-07 15:13:35.259: I/SQLiteConnectionPool(731): The connection pool for /data/data/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/databases/proizvodidb has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.
10-07 15:13:35.259: D/AndroidRuntime(731): Shutting down VM
10-07 15:13:35.259: W/dalvikvm(731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.ListaProizvoda}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/databases/proizvodidb
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/databases/proizvodidb
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:263)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.ListaProizvoda.onCreate(ListaProizvoda.java:27)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-07 15:13:35.278: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure you are only ever working with one instance of `SQLiteDatabase`. I'm guessing that you have instantiated multiple instances and Android is complaining as a result.

You should take a look at this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html) on the subject too.

Comment: the blog post link was realy useful!

Comment: I Did not make instance method as synchronized, which was causing this error.Thanks a ton

Comment: So your comment should be the real answer.