# SQLiteDatabase android IllegalStateException

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have a problem when i'm using the Sqlite of android. The log show me that :

```
SQLiteConnectionPool(1730): **The connection pool for /data/data/dev.xx.xx/databases/XX has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.**
08-02 14:15:41.490: D/AndroidRuntime(1730): Shutting down VM
08-02 14:15:41.490: W/dalvikvm(1730): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4d74908)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730): **java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/dev.xx.xx/databases/XX**
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:263)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at dev.xx.xx.SettingActivity$3.onClick(SettingActivity.java:205)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 14:15:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

This error come when i try to call :

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...
    void addUser(String who, String time, String table, String phone) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, who);
            values.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
            values.put(KEY_TABLE_RES, table);
            values.put(KEY_TIME, time);
            db.insert(TABLE_RESERVATION, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }

....
}
```

I thing it's when the func call that :

> this.getWritableDatabase()

Comment: where is this code located?

Comment: can you post how you call `addUser`. Check if you have closed before calling addUser as logcat says attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Comment: i call like that :  `DataBase db = new DataBase(context);
     db.addUser(userName.getText().toString(),table.getText().toString(),
       date.getText().toString()  + " "+ time.getText().toString(), phon.getText().toString());`

Comment: @irbiloc no do you call like `DataBase  db = new DataBase(context); db.addUser(params)`. I mean where do you call your `addUser` method

Comment: I call in a activity method.

Comment: could be your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770092/attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase

Comment: it was working very fine. The problem came when i uninstall my app while it was running in the background. When i try to re install nothing with the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you should be getting a new SQLiteDatabase instance like that every time. You want to keep a reference to the SQLiteDatabase object in your SQLiteOpenHelper. Your SQLiteOpenHelper should be constructed something more like the following:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ...
        mDatabase = db;
        ...
    }

    void addUser(String who, String time, String table, String phone) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, who);
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        values.put(KEY_TABLE_RES, table);
        values.put(KEY_TIME, time);
        mDatabase.insert(TABLE_RESERVATION, null, values);
    }

....
}
```

Comment: I added : `public static DataBase getInstance(Context ctx) {
  
  if (mDatabase == null) {
   mDatabase = new DataBase(ctx.getApplicationContext());
   db = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
  }
  return mDatabase;
 }`