# Why am I getting an IllegalStateException about re-opening an already-closed database?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Lately I've been running into some weird behavior with the SQLite Database I'm using in my app. It's mostly an IllegalStateException, saying: `IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:`

Below is a simplified version of the method that throws the error. Below that is the log.

I'm not that familiar with SQLiteDatabases, so I'm not sure if it's anything on my end. Also, none of the solutions I found online seem to be applicable to my case.

So basically, what is causing this and how can I fix it?

---

#### Edit

*24th of may '16*

I've been doing some testing, and it turns out `db.isOpen()` returns `false` in the `if else` block just below `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();`. When calling it anywhere else in the code, it returns true.
Strangely enough, `db.isReadOnly()` returns false everywhere (would expect an error/null if no database is opened).

---

```
private void updateAppUsages(@Nullable ArrayList<String> name, @Nullable ArrayList<Action> action, @Nullable ArrayList<Integer> changeAmount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_AppTable2 + " WHERE 1";

    if (name.size() != action.size() || name.size() != changeAmount.size()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updateAppUsages: Given arrays are of different length. This will not work");
    } else {
        ArrayList<Integer> returnAmountArray = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        db.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null){
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).equals(name.get(i))) {
                        returnAmountArray.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("usages")));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                c.moveToNext();
            }

            returnAmountArray.add(0);
            if (action.get(i) == Action.INCREASE) {
                returnAmountArray.set(i, returnAmountArray.get(i) + changeAmount.get(i));
            } else if (action.get(i) == Action.DECREASE) {
                returnAmountArray.set(i, returnAmountArray.get(i) - changeAmount.get(i));
                if (returnAmountArray.get(i) < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "DBHandler; appUsages: 'returnAmount' below zero. Can't be less then nothing (" + returnAmountArray.get(i) + ")");
                    return;
                }
            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            if (returnArray(AppManagerUsages.AppManagerUsages, AMUStringArg.Name).contains(name.get(i))) {
                int id = returnID(Base.AppManagerUsages, name.get(i));
                values.put(AT2_COLUMN_NAME, name.get(i));
                values.put(AT2_COLUMN_USAGES, returnAmountArray.get(i));
                db.update(TABLE_AppTable2, values, "_id=" + id, null);
            } else {
                values.put(AT2_COLUMN_NAME, name.get(i));
                values.put(AT2_COLUMN_USAGES, returnAmountArray.get(i));
                db.insert(TABLE_AppTable2, null, values);
            }
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        c.close();
    }

    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

---

```
05-23 17:03:54.733 3671-3671/com.example.tim.timapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tim.timapp, PID: 3671
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.tim.timapp/databases/TimDatabase.db
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1439)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
    at com.example.tim.timapp.CustomStuff.DBHandler.updateAppUsages(DBHandler.java:566)
    at com.example.tim.timapp.CustomStuff.DBHandler.updateAppUsages(DBHandler.java:513)
    at com.example.fragments.MainFragments.DialogFragments.AppManagerInputDialog$1.onClick(AppManagerInputDialog.java:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not the correct way to do stuff.

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023879/5721694):

---

I don't believe you should be getting a new SQLiteDatabase instance like that every time. You want to keep a reference to the SQLiteDatabase object in your SQLiteOpenHelper. Your SQLiteOpenHelper should be constructed something more like the following:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ...
        mDatabase = db;
        ...
    }

....
}
```

---

Combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023577/sqlitedatabase-android-illegalstateexception#comment26364919_18023879) comment, I created this inside my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class for myself:

```
private static SQLiteDatabase db;

public static synchronized DBHandler getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DBHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
        db = sInstance.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

So far, this has been running clean and has not given me any errors, so here's to hoping it stays that way.