# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete something from a database then insert a new value. I don't know much about databases, so would appreciate advice on whats going wrong here.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:
```

Its called from an async task, works fine the first time, but breaks the second time that the task is triggered.

Here are the important snippets:

```
 public void removeAndInsert(String configRaw) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlite = null;
    try {
        sqlite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        removeAndInsert(configRaw, sqlite);
    .....
    finally {
        if (sqlite != null) {
            sqlite.close();
        }
    }



void removeAndInsert(String configRaw, SQLiteDatabase sqlite) throws SQLException {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_RAW_DATA, configRaw);
    sqlite.delete(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    sqlite.insert(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: well this part of code looks right, are you closing somewhere else in the code ? your dbHelper class for instance?

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, its seems that something somewhere else in the app was opening and closing the database on another thread!

Comment: @serenskye Please edit your question (or post an answer) to include the details of your solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770092/attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void removeAndInsert(String configRaw) {
  SQLiteDatabase sqlite = null;
  try {
    sqlite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    synchronized(sqlite) {
      removeAndInsert(configRaw, sqlite);
    }
  .....
    finally {
    if (sqlite != null && sqlite.isOpen()) {
        sqlite.close();
    }
}

void removeAndInsert(String configRaw, SQLiteDatabase sqlite) throws SQLException {
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_RAW_DATA, configRaw);
  sqlite.delete(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
  sqlite.insert(DBOpenHelper.CONFIG_CACHE_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: The error doesn't occur on the closing line, the problem occurs when removeAndInsert is used for the second time

Comment: @serenskye I changed the example above to include synchronizing the call on the Database object.

Comment: synchronized(value) ? what is it ?, asynctask ?

Comment: I used method public synchronized void insert() //form correct... and not work this solution, I never used synchronized(sqlite) // never

Comment: isOpen(): The method isOpen() is undefined for the type SQLLiteAdapter.

I'm not able to find that method in the list.

Comment: This (sqlite != null && sqlite.isOpen()) while throw NullPointerException if sqlite object points to null. Pretty comman mistake, never check them at once.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're creating an SQLiteOpenHelper instance (`dbHelper`) somewhere and getting a writable database from it (`sqlite`), but then you close the database. If this is the last (or only) database reference that is open, then the entire database will be closed when you call `sqlite.close()`.

You can safely remove the call to `sqlite.close()` in `removeAndInsert()`. When your `AsyncTask` is finished with its database work, call `dbHelper.close()` to clean up any dangling database references.

Comment: moving where close is called, does not change the result

Comment: Your app must be closing the database elsewhere, then, as @Guru noted. Without seeing more code, we can only speculate about the source of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

try to replace   `sqlite.close();` with `dbHelper.close();`