# Occasionally getting callbacks after removeLocationUpdates()

Tags: java, android, google-api, asynccallback, google-location-services

Creating my first app,

Looking for locations using the GoogleApi and the callback is working as intended. I use the location and it gets put into a database, onDestroy() I am closing the DB connection. But now I occasionally get a stack trace saying

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase
```

I added a removeLocationUpdates() right before the closeDB call, and that MOSTLY solved the issue, but it still happens from time to time. It appears that I may still be getting a rogue callback after removeLocationUpdates and closeDB have been called.

Is this a typical delay? could a 500ms delay between the removeLocUpdates and the closeDB fix the issue? I'd imagine there'd be a better way, or that maybe I am simply doing something wrong with the removeLocUpdates. But the stack trace seems pretty clear that I am getting a callback as the trace shows

```
onLocationChanged
```

part way down the stack

EDIT to add Code:

onCreate():

```
        openDB();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    //End Google Location API implementation


    locationListener = new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //newestLocation = location;
            //bestLocation = bestLocation();
            //todo maybe come back and reimplement bestLocation() if needed
            bestLocation = location;
            getCode(null);
            saveCode(null);
        }};
```

onDestroy()

```
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
        }
    }
    closeDB();
```

onConnected()

```
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    CharSequence text = "Google API Connected";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
            .setFastestInterval(500)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setMaxWaitTime(3000)
            .setInterval(1000);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},10);
        return;
    }else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, locationListener);
    }
    return;
}
```

I appreciate your help on the matter

Comment: Might be usefull to post a part of your code so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Added some code, basically just where I start listening for location updates and where I stop.

Comment: See if this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770366/5333805

Comment: While I appreciate the link, there's definitely info to be learned there, I am quite sure my issue is that their is a call back happening after the DB has been closed (when closing out of the app, onDestroy). The error linked and the subsequent response appear to be caused by something else.