# Android Sqlite unable to delete data in two tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to make sure, that my database always contains only 10 entries of keywords and only those items of existing keywords. This is what I came up with:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        while (getKeywordsCount() > leaveN){
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(" + KEYWORDS_KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_KEYWORDS, null);
            long minId = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.close();

            db.delete(TABLE_KEYWORDS, KEYWORDS_KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(minId)});
            db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, ITEMS_KEY_KEYWORD_ID + " = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(minId)});
        }
        db.close();
```

When this method is being executed, I get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:
```

It points to line:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(" + KEYWORDS_KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_KEYWORDS, null);
```

Why is this happening? Is this because i call db.delete two times in a row?

Comment: Look at this solved issue. Pretty sure you should be facing something similar in your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770092/attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase

Comment: Are you doing this from multiple threads?

Comment: If you are... Make your helper class a singleton and don't close your connections unless it's inside a service. Android will close it for you. Alternative is from each of the threads, fire off an intent to an intent service which will do the db work... This ensures a queued operation with no issues of closing.